# How do I 'fuse' together two different kinds of data to get a final result?

Tags: robotics, sensor-fusion, control-theory

I am building a robot (2 powered wheels and one ball bearing). The problem is that I can't seem to make it drive straight. I literally find it impossible, I have been trying for weeks.

Currently I am able to rely on rotations (of both motors) or the gyro readings(I also have two gyros, each near the two tyres)

**Is there a way I can fuse those together, giving me a more accurate way to determine which motor I need to speed up?**

My motors accept a value from 0-900 (although the speed should be determined by me and not fixed). Also if an algorithm exists, I'd like some directions of what I'd need to swap if I make the motors go backwards.

Comment: "I have been trying for weeks." And what did you try? Aren't the sensor fusion and control separate sub-problems? Did you manage to solve either of these?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the robot not going straight because the rotation speeds of the two motors might be different. E.g one might be completing 30 rotations per second and the other 31. Trivially this is solved using a [wheel encoder](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12629). Using that you get the difference of rotation of two wheels and then change the motor speeds accordingly. Gyro can give you angular error per unit time, e.g if robot is moving 5 degree on the left after 2 seconds,then the right motor speed is to be decreased. But how much it needs to be decreased is not a trivial problem, because ultimately it happens because of hardware error. So what you can do is collect some data of the gyro angles, maybe 10 readings per second and analyze the data to find just how much you need to decrease the speed of one motor.